# Sort MongoDB documents by byte size

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know if it is possible to sort a MongoDB collection by the document size measured in bytes/kb. I have been checking out [db.collection.stats()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/) however this only gives me information about the collection and not the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is to add an extra "size" field in you documents, given that document size is not frequently changed.

To add size for each document:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.size = Object.bsonsize(doc); 
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

To sort in descending order:

```
db.collection.find().sort({"size":-1});
```

Another solution is to load all documents in memory, sort and print out the results with any programming language (js, php, java...), which is not recommended if your collection is big.

Answer (score 5):

From Mongo 4.4, operator `$bsonSize` returns the size in bytes of a given document.

To find biggest document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    max: { $max: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } }
  }}
])
```